# python tricontourf can not plot unregular image

Tags: python

I have data `x` (1D), `y` (1D) and `v` (1D). `x` and `y` are the coordinates, `v` is the corresponding value at the coordinate. I would like to use `tricountourf` to plot 2D image. The image is an unregular shape (like a half donuts). `v` values ranges from 0 to 1000, however I would like to use 'jet' color to distribute to [0,500], all the values bigger than 500 use red color. The colorbar only show [0,500]. I have tried long time but still can not figure it out, does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance! 
Following is my code, in my code the value bigger than 500 is white color or no color.

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()

vmin=0

vmax=500

plot_val = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, 300, endpoint=True)

cmap=plt.cm.jet

im=ax.tricontourf(x,y,v, plot_val, vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax,cmap=cmap)

im.cmap.set_over('red')

cb=fig.colorbar(im,ax=ax)

cb.set_ticks([0,100,200,300,400,500])
```